# hide element id with CSS and JavaScript based on data in console.log

Tags: javascript, css, console.log

I am trying to use an entry in console.log to determine if an element is to be hidden based on whether the console shows it as null/undefined or if it has data.

I want this to happen as the page loads

I thought what I had would work as similar code worked elsewhere to grab the data and display it on a page.
not sure what I am missing, appreciate the help.

```js
document.getElementById("learner") 
if (.window.loggedInUser.tiUserId == null) {
  style.display = 'none';
} else {
  style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

Comment: `.window.`? -> typo?

Comment: What does any of that code have to do with the  console?

Comment: so in the console the website generates the following
**Object**
email: "" firstName: "" lastName: "" tiRef9: "" tiUserId: "" and so this is what I am trying to look at, like I said similar code allowed me to pull data from this field when a user was logged in to display their name on a page.